# How to install Qt

Tags: qt, installation, window, qt-creator, valgrind

I have to install Qt on windows to create apps using C++. The problem I'm facing is that after installing qt-win-opensource-4.8.3-vs2008.exe and qt creator many of the things were abrupt. On opening qt-creator, it does not finds any examples: "Examples not found". Similarly, there is no analyze option in the menu bar of Qt creator. Can somebody help me out on how to install Qt SDK and creator on windows.

Comment: I added the path c:\Qt\4.8.3\bin and the examples are now found in Qt but there is still no Analyze option in menu bar of Qt creator

Comment: Which windows is this? XP, Vista, 7, 8?

Comment: Not a real question. It is in fact two questions : "Qt creator cannot detect examples" and "how to get valgrind to work in qt creator on windows".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still download Qt SDK from [CNET](http://download.cnet.com/Qt-SDK/3000-2069_4-75305206.html). After you've installed it, you can launch *Maintain Nokia SDK* from the Start Menu, and you can change the toolchain from Visual Studio to MinGW, as debugging doesn't work with Visual Studio toolchain.

Comment: Hi, thanks. It's working. I just had to download mingw version instead of visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

See the question I had about [QtCreator not even finding Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12599233/1122645).
Use

```
qmake -query
```

to view qmake executable variables. Make sure `QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES` and `QT_INSTALL_DEMOS` are set in order to be able to access to the example.

Answer (score 1):

The analyzer is not delivered along with Qt and has to be downloaded separately. However Valgrind does not work on Windows.

From the Qt Documentation:

> In addition, Qt Creator integrates Valgrind code analysis tools for detecting memory leaks and profiling function execution. **These tools are supported locally only on Linux and Mac OS. You can run them on a remote host from Windows.** You have to download and install them separately to use them from Qt Creator.